Synology SHR 2 disk: replace HDD with SSD
I have a DS218+ with 2x3TB WD Black, all allocated to single storage pool (SHR). The disks are hot-swappable.
The volume is almost full and I'd like to replace them with 2x4TB Crucial SSD. Only DSM 7.2 doesn't allow me since disk types don't match.
Can I still swap the disks one after the other and repair the storage pool on the command line? I have a backup of course.
NOTE
Just found his on reddit/r/synology which seems like a good advise that should work:

Synology does not allow mixed drive types in the same array. You cannot upgrade in place, as you can't replace a HDD with the SSD and rebuild.


You CAN however, pull an HDD, and add the SSD as a new pool and volume. Then copy all the data and reinstall any apps to this new pool. Then delete the old volume and pool and pull the other HDD, adding a new SSD to the new pool. Use SHR, which will be RAID1 when you're done, but give you more flexibility if you later upgrade to bigger SSDs, or move the drives to a bigger NAS so you can add more SSDs.

Not sure how copying from one pool to the other would leave the new pool in a state though to replace the old one?
